# AJAX upload triggered from a specific select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, upload, ajax-upload

I'm looking to add an option to my layout page to allow people to upload new logos on the fly. Currently users can select the image they'd like via a drop-down select element. I'd like to add an option at the end which allows them to upload a new image. I'd then refresh the image select elements with the new addition.

HTML example:

```
<select name='image_select' id='image_select_id' class='input_select' title='Select Image 1'>
  <option value='0' selected = 'selected'>--Select Logo--</option>
  <option value='test.jpg'>test.jpg</option>
  <option value='test2.jpg'>test2.jpg</option>
  <option value='add' class='upload_option'>Add new image...</option>
</select>
```

I'm using AJAXUpload for other uploading functions, but the iFrame doesn't seem to play nice in this instance. Does anyone have any suggestions about how to make this work?

Comment: is the iframe not working because of Same Origin Policy issues?

Comment: No, the upload script works fine on my other pages, and everything is on the same domain, so I can't see a SOP issue, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to uplaod an image in a AJAX way is via an iframe. If i had to advise a way i would have it so that. The user selects Add new images. An onselect function detects this and displays a form in a html box underneath. You have that form's "target" set to the ID of the iframe. Also have a onSubmit command on the form. The user hits submit, the file is sent though an iframe, you can then use the onSubmit tag to get your javascript to pull up a loading bar or what ever you want.